# Could not extract ResultSet When i using Native Query in Spring Jpa

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to get true or false, with some compare condition using Spring JPA native query. But I got following Exception,

```
could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

The query I am trying is:

```
SELECT case when ABS(am_savedagent.AGENT_VERSION)< 1.8 then 'true' else 'false' end as bool 
FROM am_savedagent where am_savedagent.BOX_ID="ots-JIO6Yn0jZbxs";
```

My Repository

```
public interface SavedAgentRepository extends JpaRepository<SavedAgentDetails, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<SavedAgentDetails> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT case when ABS(SavedAgentDetails.agentVersion)< ?1 then 'true' else 'false' end as bool FROM SavedAgentDetails where SavedAgentDetails.boxId=?2", nativeQuery = true)
    public Optional<List<Object>> findByAgentVersionAndBoxId(String currentVersion, String boxid);
}
```

I can't find y the Errors Comming. please help me, someone.

Comment: @AdyJunior The Same error will come after the change I did as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using native query =true,
that's why you need to use the table name and not the entity name inside your query.

Try this -->

```
public interface RegisterAgentRepository extends JpaRepository<RegisterAgentDetails, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<RegisterAgentDetails> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT case when ABS(am_registeragent.AGENT_VERSION)< ?1 then 'true' else 'false' end as bool FROM am_registeragent where am_registeragent.SAASBOX_ID=?2", nativeQuery = true)
    public Optional<List<Object>> findByAgentVersionAndSaasboxId(String currentVersion, String saasboxid);
}
```

Comment: Thanks For Your Response,  your answer very helpful for me.